# Spring Boot with WSO2 OAuth2 - logoutSuccessUrl is not working

Tags: spring-boot, wso2, spring-security-oauth2

We are implementing the service using Spring Boot (1.2.2) with WSO2 IS (5.x) as OAuth2 Identity provider.

As part of logout we wanted to run some cleaning activities and then redirect to login page. Following is the Spring Security Configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends OAuth2SsoConfigurerAdapter {
private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

@Autowired
private OAuth2ClientContext oAuth2ClientContext;

@Autowired
private MmaLogoutHandler logoutHandler;

@Override
public void match(RequestMatchers matchers) {
    matchers.anyRequest();
}

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .logout()
    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logoff", "GET"))
    .logoutSuccessUrl("/#/home")
    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID","remember-me")
    .permitAll()
    .and()
    .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
    .addFilterBefore(customerAuthorizationFilter(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class);
}
```

When the logout is called, the log shows that spring security has cleared the session, but it fails to redirect -

```
2015-09-01 14:23:05.983 DEBUG 12936 --- [nio-8443-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Logging out user 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication@e6269aa6: Principal: mrpink_bd3d5b71-b212-11e4-ac24-22000b4791d2; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: remoteAddress=127.0.0.1, sessionId=<SESSION>, tokenType=bearertokenValue=<TOKEN>; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER' and transferring to logout destination

2015-09-01 14:23:05.984 DEBUG 12936 --- [nio-8443-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.l.SecurityContextLogoutHandler : Invalidating session: B7B50DC106F50EDA84ACFEF229DE167B

2015-09-01 14:23:05.984 DEBUG 12936 --- [nio-8443-exec-8] .s.s.w.a.l.SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler : Using default Url: /#/home

 2015-09-01 14:23:05.984 DEBUG 12936 --- [nio-8443-exec-8] .s.s.w.a.l.SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler : Response has already been committed. Unable to redirect to /#/home

 2015-09-01 14:23:05.984 DEBUG 12936 --- [nio-8443-exec-8] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

As per log the redirection fails and the page is not actually redirected.

Is this due to OAuth2 or there is already default log out handler with Spring boot that is needed to be overridden?

Comment: I found the fix. The issue was due to Spring Cloud Security logout handler that was redirecting the response before logout success handler is invoked.

Comment: You should not put your answer on the comment. In SO you can answer your own question